# Divide NSUInteger by 100

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsuinteger

I have an NSUInteger and i want to divide it by 100. So lets say i have the number 1 in an NSUInteger i want to divide it by 100 and get 0.01 as the result.

```
(float) percent / 100
```

percent is an NSUInteger

Comment: I agree with Max, the example provided appears syntactically correct although the result is ununsed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When dividing two integers, the result will be an integer.  Make one of them a float (the constant is typical)

```
float percent = grade / 100.0f;
```

Comment: Surely that's a double? `NSLog(@"%zd %zd", sizeof(100.0), sizeof(100.0f)); //=> 8 4`

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks fine since you are casting `percent` as a float. The rule of thumb to remember is to get a floating point value you have to divide by a floating point number. This means either both numbers are a floating point number or one of the numbers are floating point. Either of the following scenarios would solve your problem.

```
//I recommend the first option
float percentage = percent / 100.0f;
float percentage = (float)percent / 100.0f;
float percentage = (float)percent / 100;
```